# Как заставить UrlManager объединить несколько get-параметров в один?

Tags: yii, yii2

В конфиге настроено следующим образом:

```
'parts/<group:[\w_\/-]+>/<subgroup:[\w_\/-]+>/<nodes:.+>'=>'node/view',
```

При переходе по ссылке вида

*сайт_точка_ру/parts/geely/ck/node-1/node2/110-10-040*

В queryParams получается массив следующего содержания

```
array (size=3)
  'group' => string 'geely/ck/node-1' (length=15)
  'subgroup' => string 'node2' (length=5)
  'nodes' => string '110-10-040' (length=10)
```

В данном случае несколько параметров, принадлежащих узлу записались в параметр группы

А должно быть так:

```
array (size=3)
  'group' => string 'geely' (length=6)
  'subgroup' => string 'ck' (length=2)
  'nodes' => string 'node-1/node2/110-10-040' (length=24)
```

Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: А зачем там у каждого параметра `\/-` ? Если написать `parts/<group:[\w_]+>/<subgroup:[\w_]+>/<nodes:.+>'=>'node/view` не прокатит?

Comment: Спасибо, вы оказались правы